# How to force ssh client to use only password auth?

Tags: ssh, password, key-authentication

If I use pubkey auth from e.g.: an Ubuntu 11.04 how can I set the ssh client to use only password auth to a server? (just needed because of testing passwords on a server, where I default log in with key)

I found a way:

```
mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.backup
mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.backup
```

and now I get prompted for password, but are there any offical ways?

Answer (score 1049, accepted):

Disable [**PubkeyAuthentication**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#PubkeyAuthentication) and also set [**PreferredAuthentications**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#PreferredAuthentications) to `password` so that alternative methods like gssapi-with-mic aren't used:

```bash
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password  example.com
```

You need to make sure that the client isn't configured to disallow password authentication.

Comment: I needed to enforce the password prompt to appear in an environment where Kerberos was used for automated authentication, and a similar command worked for me in that specific situation:  
  
    `ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no example.com`

Comment: Nice. Only `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no` was sufficient in my case.

Comment: @mivk same here.

Comment: to ssh into a friend osx laptop, I had to use: `-o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no ` instead

Comment: @guido: Same here. I bet it's not OS X related, though, but rather has to do with OpenSSH versions.

Comment: my 5cent. I have normal sshd on port 22, that accept passwords and PK. Firewall is configured to allow only specific IP addresses on port 22. Then i have second sshd on different port that accept only PK.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It keeps saying: *Permission denied (publickey).* and never offers a password prompt.

Comment: @reinierpost that's likely because the ssh *host* has disabled `PasswordAuthentication`. In fact, I'm here because I wanted to test that disabling password auth worked correctly on my host.

Comment: @reinierpost I had the same problem as you, and changing `password` with `keyboard-interactive` make it work, as spotted by guido : `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive -o PubkeyAuthentication=no me@example.com`

Comment: The host had enabled PasswordAuthentication but I never tried keyboard-interactive. I don't recall where I had the problem, but I will bear this in mind, thanks.

Comment: Make sure you've enabled password access on the server: https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-enable-ssh-password-authentication/

Comment: I was getting `Permission denied (publickey,password)` which seemed to suggest that a password should be accepted, but none of the options above would actually cause ssh to prompt me for the password.  Turns out it was a configuration error in `~/.ssh/config` that was setup to use key authentication.  Who knew this prevents all command line options from taking effect!

Comment: @tobiasBora: I know password authentication is enabled, as it works for other accounts on the same server. @Finesse: this is not my server and I cannot even read its `sshd_config`.

Comment: I had to add another option: `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`. Otherwise it may bail out with an error `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED`. This may happen for example if remote host has a system booted different to the one you had originally key generated for.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1684034/329627 this was the correct solution for me.  `ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication yes"  user@host`

Answer (score 258):

I've discovered a shortcut for this purpose:

```
ssh user:@example.com
```

Note the colon (`:`) and the empty password after it.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: No documentation yet. Actually, I've skimmed through the OpenSSH source code to no avail (its parsing stage is rather cryptic and it's morning here :)). My initial motivation: many clients prompt for a password if you give an empty password, e.g. `mysql -u user -p`

Comment: I don't expect another answer will come up I like better, but I will leave the bounty open for a bit so this Q gets more attention. After reviewing this answer, I originally posted on the chat site to draw some attention to it, which got you some upvotes. But I hope  the bounty gets you some more attention as well.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that this is not very fragile and meets the expectations. By the way, the question [Why doesn't the ssh command follow RFC on URI?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75668/why-doesnt-the-ssh-command-follow-rfc-on-uri) and the answers there seem relevant.

I guess the modus operandi here is that OpenSSH sees the empty password, having discovered that the remote sshd doesn't allow empty passwords, prompts the user for one, or something like that. I'm hoping to take another shot at the source code when I have some time.

Comment: Note that everything after the colon seems to get stripped (it doesn't help that the whole string gets displayed on the password prompt, though), `ssh user:foobar@example.com` works just as well. I don't particularly like the way this behaves but have an upvote for finding out :-)

Comment: Beautiful, you just hacked the parser.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, at least not in my case. `ssh` client was blindly trying unrelated private keys to authenticate to a newly installed server and keep in being rejected due to the maximum amount of tries being reached without ever asking for the password. In order to force password authentication for this first connection, I had to to use `-o PreferredAuthentications=password` syntax, the colon trick having no noticeable effect. So while this trick may be worth to try, one should not rely on it as a consistent behavior.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf indeed, the parser must have changed in the meantime.

Comment: It doesn't always work for me. Depending on the server, sometimes it does, sometimes no.

Comment: @Qualcuno as WhiteWinterWolf said, it doesn't work on some platforms anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: Would be nice to have the actual SSH versions where this used to work.

Comment: @kaiser I have an older system at work behind the firewall.  Still works on ssh client version OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have PasswordAuthentication no on your ssh_config file!

Comment: I must say this is the best answer ever to this question, so simple and perfectly working.

Comment: What an awesome shortcut! Still works for me in 2022. FYI 'ssh -V' returns: "OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022".

Answer (score 53):

As well as the method posted by scoopr, you can set per host options in your ssh client configuration file.

In your `.ssh` directory, create a file called `config` (if it doesn't already exist) and set the permissions to `600`, you can then create sections which start with

```
host <some hostname or pattern>
```

and then set per host options after that, for example,

```
host bob.specific.foo
user fred

host *.home.example
user billy
port 9191
```

so you could have

```
host server.to.test
PubkeyAuthentication no
```

in that file, and then simply

```
ssh server.to.test
```

and the option will get picked up.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I created an entry in my `~/.ssh/config` and added `PubkeyAuthentication no`

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: This solved my issue.

Comment: The config actually needs to be `PubkeyAuthentication no` note that the `=` sign is not required in `~/.ssh/config` file

Comment: This is what finally worked today! Spent far too much time on other options. I think partially because my server is older and cursed  and I have no clue how I set it up in the past since it doesn't seem to want to honor anything in the authorized_keys on the server.

Answer (score 22):

I recently needed this but none of the options above worked, `ssh -v` showed that the command-line options passed via the `-o` switch were over-ridden by the values specified in my `~/.ssh/config` file.

What worked was this:

```
ssh -F /dev/null <username>@<host>
```

From the `ssh` man page:

```
 -F configfile
     Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a
     configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide
     configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored. The default 
     for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.
```

Credits to this answer: [How can I make ssh ignore .ssh/config?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110283/how-can-i-make-ssh-ignore-ssh-config)

Comment: this does not answer the question. You can always have the keys stored in agent and your approach will not prevent client from using them.

Comment: Hm, how would one remediate *that* issue as well as the one I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Also if you have the keys in standard location (as in the question), they will be used regardless the config is present or not. I would go with one of the methods mentioned in the first answers.

Comment: Not quite true, I just tested it out on my Lubuntu 14.04 and even though I have my keys in the standard location `~/.ssh/config`, the keys don't get used if I specify `-F /dev/null`. `ssh -v` output helps in this case, it clearly shows that because I have a catch-all entry in my ssh config for `*`, it elects to use the public key rather than respect the options passed via the `-o` switch as in the former answers.

Comment: Standard location is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` as stated in manual page. These paths are hardcoded in the client. Just make sure you provide the correct user when testing.

Comment: My bad, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is what I meant -- just re-tested it out though -- just using the command I mentioned above, I'm able to SSH into my server without the need for any other command line options of the older answers.

Comment: As a short-cut to overriding the `.ssh/config` file I often use `-F.`, pointing the ssh client to use `.` - which means the current directory rather than a specific file.  You'd think that would be invalid but it accepts it and it's less to type than `-F /dev/null`.

Answer (score 11):

I tried a few of these answers, but `ssh -v` kept showing my public keys getting pulled out of my home directory. However, [specifying a bogus identity file](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i) did the trick for me:

```bash
ssh -i /dev/null host
```

I have to do this permanently (to work around the broken SSH server in an APC rack-mounted PDU — stay **far** away from these things if you care about security), so I ended up putting the option into my config file:

```
Host apc1 apc2
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
IdentityFile /dev/null
```

Comment: `Permissions 0666 for '/dev/null' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
`

Comment: This works perfectly and is far easier (both to remember and less typing!) than the top voted answer.  Sad how many other answers here are blatantly wrong / out dated.

Comment: This is great to test if password authentication works (i.e. if you have the right password), despite having a key file locally. So you can test if you can still access the server whenever you lose your key somehow.

Answer (score 9):

This is mentioned in a comment above, but I think it deserves to be its own answer.

For people receiving the `Permission denied (publickey)` error despite the other solutions here, the problem is likely that the *server* is set not to accept passwords. To change this, you need to get into the server (many services will allow you to access with a password via a virtual console on their management console) and:

1. `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Find `PasswordAuthentication no` and change it to `yes`, and uncomment it.
3. Run `sudo service sshd restart` (or `sudo systemctl restart sshd` if using systemd services)
4. Now try to log in, from a remote server, using one of the methods above, such as `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no example.com`

Comment: Nice, from point 1 to 3 worked for me. (Just with small change: sudo systemctl restart sshd)

Comment: When you look at the output generated by `ssh -v` you see the following line `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password`. If `password` is missing then none of the client side solutions on this page are going to help you.

Answer (score 3):

@scoopr and @Halil Özgür answers didn't work for me.

This worked for me:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com
```

Source: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking.html

Comment: The question is about client authentication by password. This answer is about checking if the servers host key matches one in known hosts. In effect it is answering a different question

Answer (score 3):

I may be the only one in the world with this issue, but I had an `ssh` from another operating system running (choco ssh in Windows in a cygwin shell) seen via `which ssh`

So the solution was to

```
 /usr/bin/ssh user@example.com
```

Note the full path. I did this after I had run `cyg-get openssh`

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but I had to set the `ControlPath` option to `none` because I had an already established connection by the means of *SSH connection sharing*. So authentication was skipped instead of asking for a password. If it's same for you try following command line.

`ssh -o ControlPath=none -o PreferredAuthentications=password example.org`

Comment: That was it for me: `-o PreferredAuthentications=password`

Answer (score 2):

And also be sure, there is no `BatchMode=yes` active in .ssh/config.
Otherwise you've got no chance, to get an interactive password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried just about everything suggested, including setting
`PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the host, and lots of different arguments to `ssh` on the client, but still got `Permission denied (pubkey)`.

Then I noticed, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the host, the line:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

and wondered what config that might be pulling in that seemed to be overriding `PasswordAuthentication yes`. I commented it out (and restarted sshd) - and now I can log in by doing simply `ssh user@host`!

Both the client and server are DigitalOcean Ubuntu "droplets" (servers), one of which is messed up because of an aborted `do-release-upgrade`, and I am just trying to migrate the data from the old one (the client) to the new one (the host). Because I only have access to a recovery console on the old server through the web from which I can't copy any text (e.g. a pubkey) and if I try to paste a pubkey into `authorized_keys` through the web the paste gets screwed up - and I really want to avoid typing in a pubkey by hand! - I have been trying to ssh to the new server using a password rather than a pubkey so found this question. Hopefully I can now start to transfer some data with scp or rsync. But I have had to comment out that `Include` to do it, which may not be a safe or desirable thing to do in the long term - I just did it to be able to migrate my data. So be careful! But it might help if you're in a similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I resolved the issue by using [`-i`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i) to specify the private key for the target VM. For example:

```bash
ssh -i /path/to/private_key <username>@<vm_ip>
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked. The OP has a key but wants to use a password