# Why doesn't the ssh command follow RFC on URI?

Tags: ssh, openssh

The RFC:

- [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Scheme for Secure File Transfer
  Protocol (SFTP) and Secure Shell (SSH)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-3)

presents the SSH URI as:

```
ssh://[<user>[;fingerprint=<host-key fingerprint>]@]<host>[:<port>]
```

Are there any known reasons why the OpenSSH ssh command doesn't follow this standard with the hostname option? It does not accept a port after a colon.

Example of a URI I was expecting to work:

```
$ ssh user@host:2222
ssh: Could not resolve hostname host:2222: Name or service not known
```

Comment: I think @MichaelKjörling is correct. The colon is the boundary for where the hostname stops and the path starts on that host. You need to use the `-p` switch to convey an alternate port.

Comment: That's not a RFC, that's a draft that hasn't been followed through since 2006.

Comment: I agree that [rfc3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3986/) would have been more appropriate to quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh` predates the more general URI format ([1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier)) by several years (1995 IIRC).

Comment: So you are saying that the draft of [RFC 1738](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738) published in December 1994 could not have influenced OpenSSH development? _OpenSSH first appeared in OpenBSD 2.6 and the first portable release was made in October 1999_ following [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH#History). Unless it had to be compatible with the ssh.com tools?

Comment: RFC 1738 is for URLs and was in my recollection not so generic a format and later generalised in URIs. openssh is much later as ssh, I don't remember having made the transition so there is a good chance they are commandline compatible to a large extent.

Answer (score 17):

I originally posted this as a comment, but will flesh it out a little as an answer.

OpenSSH contains several utilities, among the most notable of which are `ssh` and `scp`. While `ssh` will only connect to a remote computer (and possibly execute a command on that remote computer), other parts of OpenSSH such as `scp` have a slightly different syntax. By virtue of all being part of the OpenSSH suite, these likely share a lot of code.

With `scp`, you specify a remote file on a triplet form as `user@host:remotefilename`, where `remotefilename` may be a relative or absolute path.

**If the host portion was allowed to be on the form `host:port`**, this would create a potential ambiguity: does `jdoe@host.example.com:2222` refer to `~jdoe/2222` on host.example.com when connecting on the standard port, or does it refer to no file at all (or worse, `~jdoe`) on host.example.com when connecting over port 2222?

The URI syntax that you present is more limited in what it can express (it doesn't allow for a filename specification), and even more importantly, there can never be ambiguity unless the actual *host name* includes a `:` (which I don't think is even possible in DNS, and certainly isn't commonly done, whereas all-numeric file names aren't all that unusual).

**When SSH was originally developed**, it was developed as a more secure, drop-in replacement for the earlier RSH/rlogin suite of tools. I don't know what the command-line syntax for that was back in the early 1990s (the RFC describing rlogin is [RFC 1282 from December 1991](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1282), predating the document you cite by about 15 years), but it doesn't seem an unreasonable guess that it used a very similar syntax because the user name was transmitted specially in the rlogin protocol. Quoting RFC 1282:

> Upon connection establishment, the client sends four null-terminated strings to the server.  The first is an empty string (i.e., it consists solely of a single zero byte), followed by three non-null strings: the client username, **the server username**, and the terminal type and speed.  More explicitly: ...

The local username can be obtained through various system facilities, but the remote username must be specified explicitly *somehow*. Aside from `@` often being pronounced "at" and thus being a pretty natural choice to begin with, `user@host` maps well to established syntax for e.g. email transmission (compare a SMTP address of `user@host`, where `host` may be an actual host or a DNS name with a MX record pointing to an actual host), so it was probably an easy choice rather than making up something new.

**It's also worth noting** what Stephane Chazelas pointed out in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75668/why-doesnt-the-ssh-command-follow-rfc-on-uri/75673#comment110386_75668): the document you refer to isn't an RFC, it's a currently seven years old draft which, judging by a quick Google search to confirm, seems to never have gotten off the ground. That happens all the time; something is proposed, but does not garner the support to actually make it into an RFC (and even many, *many* RFCs are non-standards).

Comment: I guess my question should have been "Why do OpenSSH utilities not follow the general URI standards?". While I appreciate your insight it did not answer my question.

Comment: +1 historical perspective is useful in charting the chaotic sea of standards

Comment: To expand on the comment "many RFCs are non-standards", this couldn't be further from the truth. The very nature of an RFC is a "Request For Comment"; it is merely informational. It may be a note, a memo, or documentation. An RFC is merely a published memo; RFCs are simply also one of the many ways standards documentation are published, albeit this is not the sole purpose of an RFC. A standard may be documented via an RFC, but an RFC is not always documentation for a specific standard. A banana is a fruit, but not all fruits are bananas.

Comment: @Swivel doesn't this mean that the statement "many RFCs are non-standards" is true, if an understatement? Many fruits are non-bananas.

Comment: @mwfearnley HAHA. Absolutely. I apologize. What I think I meant to say was: "To expand on the comment 'many RFCs are non-standards', this couldn't be more true." The timestamp shows it was about ~0:14 local time, so I was probably overdue for a snooze. (The irony, of course, is that I'm posting this at 01:59 local time right now).