# How can I make ssh ignore .ssh/config?

Tags: ssh

I have the following in my ~/.ssh/config.

```
HOST 10.2.192.*
        USER foo
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo/id_rsa
```

The above configuration lets me connect to a machine while typing half as many words.

```
 ssh 10.2.192.x
```

Before my ssh config, I had  to type in all of this:

```
 ssh foo@10.2.192.x -i ~/.ss/foo/id_rsa
```

However there is one machine in the 10.2.192.x subnet that I want to connect to with password based authentication instead of keybased authentication.

Because ssh looks at my config file and finds a match for `PreferredAuthentications publickey` I am unable to login with just my password.

I don't intend to ssh into this special snowflake vm often enough to warrant adding a new rule to my ssh config.

How can I make ssh ignore my config file just this once, and allow me to authenticate with a password?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

To make your `ssh` client ignore your configuration file, use `ssh -F /dev/null username@example.com`.  Because your subnet's IdentityFile is in `~/.ssh/foo` rather than `~/.ssh/`, you don't need to whip up a whole new file to eschew your extant private key.

From the `ssh` man page:

```
 -F configfile
     Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a
     configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide
     configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored. The default 
     for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.
```

Answer (score 25):

I believe that this question is already answered by: [How to force ssh client to use only password auth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth)

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no example.com
```

Comment: Ah, but the actual question (notwithstanding its title), after all the preamble, was: "How can I make ssh ignore my config file just this once, and allow me to authenticate with a password?"