# How to force ssh-copy-id to ignore existing authorized keys?

Tags: ssh

Edit: There's a [bug report for this](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2331), doing the equivalent of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184213/3645).

I'm trying to script the copying of public keys to multiple machines. `ssh-copy-id` checks whether it can log in with the current configuration before copying, but unfortunately this includes any `IdentityFile` entries in `~/.ssh/config`. I would like to **completely ignore `~/.ssh/config`**; is there some way to do that, or to **force `ssh-copy-id` to always add the key?** This does *not* work:

```
ssh-add "$old_key"
ssh-copy-id -i "$new_key" -o "IdentityFile $new_key" "$login"
```

This is similar to, but distinct from [How can I make ssh ignore .ssh/config?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110283/how-can-i-make-ssh-ignore-ssh-config).

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` is itself a shell script. You can try editing it.

Comment: You can force adding `PreferredAuthentications password` & `PubkeyAuthentication no` for required host in `~/.ssh/config`. You will use password for `ssh-copy-id` authentication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking the code of `ssh-copy-id`, it turns out this hack works:

```
SSH_OPTS='-F /dev/null' ssh-copy-id [...]
```

Would still be interested in a solution that only relies on documented features, though.

Comment: If there is such a feature, would you not have encountered it while checking the code ;-)

Comment: I guess you could consider my answer a hint that this *should* be a supported feature :)

Comment: File a wishlist bug?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'd be happy to, but I have no idea where it's maintained. There's bug reports all over the place, and no reference in the file itself. Any idea?

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` is part of `OpenSSH`, which is is maintained by the OpenBSD people. Looks like they use Bugzilla. See http://www.openssh.com/report.html. Some `copy-id` bugs have been reported recently. See https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=&no_redirect=1&order=changeddate%20DESC%2Cpriority%2Cbug_severity&product=&query_based_on=&query_format=specific

Comment: `dpkg -L openssh-client |grep SSH_OPTS` returns nothing on my system (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: @Gilles Curious. Why should a file listing mention an environment variable?

Comment: @muru I meant `dpkg -L openssh-client |xargs grep SSH_OPTS`, i.e. none of the files in the package use the variable `SSH_OPTS`, or else they construct it dynamically (which is unlikely). In particular, the `ssh-copy-id` script from OpenSSH portable 5.9 doesn't mention `SSH_OPTS`. It's present in 6.6 (on Ubuntu 14.04), but not documented.

Comment: @Gilles It does on Ubuntu 14.04 (6.6p1-2ubuntu1) and Arch Linux (OpenSSH 6.7p1-1). Might have been introduced later on. Oh, didn't see your edit.

Comment: @muru And on 6.6, the alternate method `ssh-copy-id -o -F -o /dev/null …` (which wasn't present in 5.9) is documented in the man page.

Comment: @Gilles It is? I can't find it on http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.html

Answer (score 2):

The use of `SSH_OPTS` may not be future-proof (I think that the script should reset it at the beginning for security reasons: the behavior shouldn't depend on unspecified environment variables, which may have not been cleaned up in some cases). What you could do (possibly via a shell function):

```
env PATH="/path/to/special_dir:$PATH" ssh-copy-id [...]
```

where `/path/to/special_dir` just contains a `ssh` script, which can execute the real `ssh` with `-F /dev/null`. This is a bit ugly, but I don't think that there is any clean way with the current `ssh-copy-id` script.

Comment: This relies on `ssh-copy-id` using `PATH` to resolve `ssh`, which may *also* change (Unlikely, but still). +1 for a clever hack.