# ssh login with password impossible - no prompt offered- Too many authentication failures

Tags: opensuse, raspberry-pi, sshd

I am trying to log in to a fresh installation of openSUSE Leap 42.2 on a Raspberry Pi. The setup if completely default, and there are no public keys stored on the pi.

When I try to log in via `ssh root@192.168.1.56` I get an error:

```
Received disconnect from 192.168.1.56 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Connection to 192.168.1.56 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.1.56 closed.
```

Using `ssh -v` reveals that lots of public keys are being offered:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/robert/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/robert/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: robert@XXX
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: robert@yyy
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: robert@zzz
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: backup-login@xxx
```

Which I assume count for an authentication attempt each and cause the server to stop talking to me.

Sure enough, when I log in from a different user account, the password prompt appears.

On the server the following error message appears

```
Dec 09 20:27:18 linux sshd[1020]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 192.168.1.52 port 35088 ssh2 [preauth]
```

To work around this tried to force password authentication as described at [How to force ssh client to use only password auth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth):

```
ssh  -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no root@192.168.1.56
```

which now lead to

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

How can I get password-based login working in this situation?

Comment: See also this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/880971/60285

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"password" and "keyboard-interactive" are two different authentication types; the host is offering the later. So you need to use that in your preferred authentication list:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive …
```

Comment: see https://superuser.com/a/894625/180404 for the difference between password and keyboard-interactive

Comment: Interesting, thanks @JonnyJD