# ssh onto remote machine using ONLY public key

Tags: ssh

I'm sshing into a remote host and it's picking gssapi-with-mic authentication. How do I set at command line to only use public key? I don't have access to the remote server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config and it seems all the recommendation is for changing the config rather than command line option.

Comment: Related: [How to force ssh client to use only password auth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth)

Answer (score 5):

That should be with:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey host
```

The default value of `PreferredAuthentications` according to the manual is: `gssapi-with-mic,hostbased,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
ssh -o " AllowedAuthentication=publickey" -i path/to/private_key username@hostname
```

For the record your private key is located (usually) in `~/.ssh` directory

Comment: From the manual, I'm not convinced it would cause `publickey` auth to take precedence over gssapi-with-mic. It would rather bypass the authentication agent.